# Check if a string is in List case-insentive

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I check for a String regardless of case that is already in a List of strings or not?

I have this

```
current_activities = ['Free WiFi']

if activity in current_activities:
   print("Yes it is already inside")
```

I want that whether `activity = 'Free WiFi'` or `activity = 'Free WIFI'`  it should evaluate to true.

Comment: Both are same I guess "activity = 'Free WIFI' or activity = 'Free WIFI' "

Comment: Sorry ... I have edited .... look now

Comment: I have tried the solution from the question which is marked duplicate but does not work

Comment: It worked for you ? @mani

Comment: ok as the answers section is being disables so I will try to answer you in the comments itself....

Comment: for word in current_activities:
    if word.lower()==activity.lower():
        print "Yes it is already inside"

Comment: Please indent the code accordingly, and keep in mind that it will also accept "free wifi", "FREE wifi", "FrEE WiFi" ,etc.

Comment: Can you just modify my code to answer question? You have adde more `FOR` loops .... :P

Comment: Sorry but Stackoverflow is not allowing extended conversations in comments, so You have to go with it or contact me somewhere else.

Comment: remove the email comment to avoid spams, gmail would be preferable :)